# How do the A.I. Builds behave

Tags: starcraft-2

If you choose custom game in starcraft 2 you can choose of different builds for the A.I.:

- Full Rush
- Timing Attack
- Aggressive Push
- Economic Focus
- Straight to air

What is the difference between those builds?

Comment: Depends on the race. If you switch from "Random" to one of the three specific races, it'll list actual strats (i.e., "Roach Rush"), and then what kind of build it is.

Comment: I was searching for a description for each build, but couldn't find any

Comment: Hm. Wonder if they're listed in the AI Editor.

Comment: easy way to find out put 2 AIs against each other with these strats

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Full rush:**
Just means what it means: the AI will build up forces as soon as possible without researching upgrades through the Engineering Bay, Forge, or Evolution Chamber, trying to finish the game early.

**Timing attack:**
The timing attack depends on the race you're up against. There are several timing attacks programmed into the AI:

*Against Protoss:*
Blink-Stalker,
[Stalker Robo](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/3_Stalker_Robo),
Dark Templar,
[Four Gate](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/index.php?title=4_Warpgate_Rush).

*Against Zerg:*
[Baneling Bust](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Baneling_Bust),
Roach Rush,
Ling Roach,
Mutalisk.

*Against Terran:*
Marine Stim,
Marine Siegetank,
Marauder Helion,
Cloaked Banshee.

**Aggressive push:**
I believe (need some input) this mode will do a timing push as well but with everything the AI has with a focus on winning the game on the push ("timing push" means for example getting an upgrade and attacking right as it finishes before the opponent has gotten his own upgrade that would allow him to defend it)

**Economic focus:**
This is the macro mode, building up economy and practising the long game.

**Straight to air:**
Speaks for itself. Rushing an AI opponent that uses this build would be pretty much an automatic win. This mode is for practising air battles.

Comment: now for the next question; can you have the AI cheese you?

Comment: Yes, start a game with full rush and get a drink when the game starts. But seriously, no that is not programmed in.

Comment: thanks. Where did you find all this info?

Comment: @rubo77 - The names describe them.  The timing attack can be determined by playing.

Comment: @rubo77 Yeah a bit of googling but most from own experience and knowing the game and acronyms pretty well.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify "leaving tech" and "timing push", you can delete your comments

Comment: In a "Full Rush" will the AI still research upgrades in other buildings?